# Kubernetes and OIDC, how can it be secure without claim validation?

Tags: security, kubernetes, authorization, openid-connect

I'm trying to configure OIDC login to my Kubernetes, and I'm a bit troubled by some security aspects of it.

From what I gathered, it doesn't check the scopes from the ID token, which would mean any ID token delivered by my Identity provider for my user could have access to my cluster.
Which means the backend of another service (not even managed by me), that uses the same identity provider, could potentially access my cluster on my behalf. However, this doesn't seem like something people worry about.

Why ? What is wrong with my reasoning ?
Please enlighten me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your application will only accept/trust tokens (ID/Access) from the specific token provider you trust. The tokens are signed using the token provider's private key, and your application will only accept those tokens signed by this key. Your applications are configured to typically only trust tokens from one issuer.

Tokens from other sources should be rejected by the applications if they are properly configured (there have been some [examples](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) in the past).

Comment: So If i understood correctly, when implementing an OIDC provider, I should generate a different jwt signing key for each client and use it only for the ID tokens of this client.

Comment: Or rather I should at least use a separate one for "sensitive" applications that do not need interoperability with other apis.

Comment: A given token issuer/service can have one or multiple keys. Then there are many layers of security within a typical openid connect setup, one is the claims inside the tokens, for example an API receiving an access token, can besides validate the signature , also check, is this token meant for me (checking the aud claim), is the token issued by someone I trust? (the iss claim).

Comment: the signing key is one layer, allowing to verify who issued the received token. If the signature is ok, then you know what you can trust the content of the token. When the token is trusted, you start verifying the various claims inside the token. Then after verifying the token, you check for authorization, is this token allowed to perform the requested action?

Comment: Okay thank you very much for the clarification. I understand how the claims can be used by an API to check for authorization. But I don't think kubernetes performs this second layer vérification. Therefore the jwt signing key is the only authentication and authorization mechanism available, it feels like a limitation.

Comment: I can't speak for how Kubernetes deals with token security. It is also important that you keep authentication and authorizations as two separate concepts when processing tokens. You always first check authentication (who is the user) and then authorization (what is he allowed to do?)

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: With regard to OIDC, your answer was thorough, and I have no question any more on that topic. Thank you very much. However, I still hope someone will answer the Kubernetes part of the question.

Comment: also, don't forget that the ID-token typically is only used to establish a session and that the id-token have a very short lifetime, 5 minutes in some setup. the access token is what you use to access protected resources.